# __repr__, __str__ lack of understanding

Tags: python, string, class, repr

I am right now studying Python classes and running into a thing which book doesn't explain much.

I have a code :

```
class Human(object):
    def __init__(self,*args,**kwargs):
        self.first_name = kwargs.setdefault('first')
        self.last_name = kwargs.setdefault('last')
        self.height = kwargs.setdefault('height')
        self.weight = kwargs.setdefault('weight')

def bmi(self):
    return self.weight/float(self.height)**2
Human.bmi = bmi

def human_str(self):
    return '{} {}'.format(self.first_name, self.last_name)
Human.__str__ = human_str

me = Human(first='Seth', last='Gibson')   
adam_mechtley = Human(first='Adam', last='Mechtley', weight = 78, height = 1.85) 
sis = Human(first='Ruth',last='Gibson')
babysis = Human(first='Emily',last='Gibson')
print(sis)
#Prints : proper name
print(sis,babysis)
#Prints : <place in memory>
```

I understand overall what's happening , but
the question is, why when I print only one instance, **str**() attribute works, but if I try to print two instances at the same time, **repr**() attribute is being used?

Thanks for your time!

Comment: That sure is a backwards way of defining a class

Comment: If this was Python 3, I'd say that `print(x)` uses `__str__`, while `print((x,y))` calls `__str__` of `tuple`, which internally calls `__repr__` of the elements, but it does not print the `(...)` in Python 2, i.e. not a tuple. Might still be something like that.

Comment: Cannot reproduce.  When I run this code in Python 2.7.10, I get `Ruth Gibson<newline>Ruth Gibson Emily Gibson` as the output.

Comment: Actually, on closer inspection, I can not reproduce the problem either, using `Python 2.7.15rc1`, neither with this "backwards" way, nor with proper `def __str__(self)`, nor with both `str` and `repr`.

Comment: Sorry, guys did a small mistake instead of 'print sis' and 'print sis,babysis', should be  'print(sis)' and 'print(sis,babysis)'. Sorry for confusion, parentheses was missing. Then my question will make sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason is that in Python 2, `print(a,b)` does not print `a` and `b`, but it prints `(a, b)`, i.e. a `tuple`. Thus, `print(a)` will call `str(a)` (the `(...)` won't make a single element into a tuple), whereas `print(a,b)` calls the `__str__` of the tuple `(a, b)`, which in turn calls the `__repr__` of the individual elements. (And if no `__repr__` is defined, then it will print the type and memory address by default.)

Minimal example:

```
class Test:
    def __str__(self):
        return "str"
    def __repr__(self):
        return "repr"

t = Test()
print(t)
print(t, t)
```

Output using Python 2:

```
str
(repr, repr)
```

On Python 3, on the other hand, or when doing `print t, t` in Python 2, without the `(...)`, `print` will call `str` on both elements directly.

```
str
str str
```

---

Also, unrelated to the problem, I'd suggest changing your `Human` class to something like this, defining proper methods and not using `kwargs`.

```
class Human(object):
    def __init__(self, first, last, height=None, weight=None):
        self.first_name = first
        self.last_name = last
        self.height = height
        self.weight = weight

    def bmi(self):
        return self.weight/float(self.height)**2

    def __str__(self):
        return '{} {}'.format(self.first_name, self.last_name)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a more normal way to define the class that you wrote earlier

```
class Human(object): 
    def __init__(self,*args,**kwargs):
        self.first_name = kwargs.setdefault('first')
        self.last_name = kwargs.setdefault('last')
        self.height = kwargs.setdefault('height')
        self.weight = kwargs.setdefault('weight') 
    def bmi(self):
        return self.weight/float(self.height)**2
    def __str__(self):
        return '{0} {1}'.format(self.first_name, self.last_name)
```

The rest of your question is probably answered here: 
[Difference between __str__ and __repr__?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1436703/difference-between-str-and-repr)